# The proof of Perron-Frobenius Theorem

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can someone recommend me a book where I can find a detailed proof of the Perron-Frobenius Theorem for nonnegative matrices?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Varga, Richard S. *Matrix iterative analysis*. Vol. 27. Springer Science & Business Media, 2009 has a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be many, but just to mention a couple of standard references on matrices:

- *Matrices: Theory and Applications* by Denis Serre. (Sect. 8.2–3 in the second edition.)
- *Matrix Analysis* by Horn & Johnson. (Sect. 8.4 in the second edition.)